# SSRS Drillthrough report - parameter passing

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, parameter-passing, drillthrough

I have one report with columnName called as 'referenceName'. Two rows get displayed on this report with two different values for 'referenceName' column. 
When I am click on the first/second value in the 'referenceName' column only first value gets passed to the next drill through report. Why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason for this error was that I was passing the value of the parameter instead of name of the parameter. so, I was passing '@ReferenceName' instead of [ReferenceName].